# Any use case for SOAP over SMTP/JMS?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, jax-ws, soa

I've frequently used SOAP over HTTP for web services that so far worked great and with REST this is only choice we're left with.

I would like to know If you've come across a use case/scenario in your projects that needs SOAP over SMTP or SOAP over JMS type of communication? I'm just trying to understand uses of SMTP or JMS with SOAP?

Answer (score 6):

Both SMTP, and most JMS implementations, provide queueing of messages.  If you need to reliably send a message to an endpoint that may not be available, they are both reasonable choices.

JMS implementations often add additional properties, such as in-order delivery, the ability to select the appropriate level of assurance (eg: at least once, only once, etc), the ability to load-balance processing more easily, and various topologies such as broadcast or fan-out.

These are really properties of the underlying transport, and would be equally valid if you replaced SOAP with "custom JSON", XML, or any other message encoding in your question.